# Adding Dynamic custom controls into view with RxSwift from View model

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I recently started working using RxSwift. I do have some basic knowledge now. I have a view controller for which I have created corresponding View model and I have some properties defined and are bound to some labels on the view in view controller. This binding works fine.

I also have some custom controls which are added dynamically into a scrollview in the view controller based on certain conditions in the api response. Since the API call is made through view model, view model would have the complete response and is straight forward to set the properties which are bound with the labels controls on the view. Here is the scenario for which I need some idea or hints

Based on some flags in the API response I need to tell view to dynamically add custom control A, B, C into the scroll view and pass the required data to the custom controls to populate. And the data to be passed to custom controls is with view model.

Is it recommended to create view model even for custom controls? If yes, how can I manage to handle the above scenario and comply with MVVM pattern using RxSwift. Basically since the complete data is with view model of the view controller, how to share this data with custom controls in the best possible way and at the same time comply with MVVM pattern and keep the code structured.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the your custom control, if you have to handle a lot of business logic/data inside it, then that view should have its own view model

To think of it like this, in the application we have view controllers, a view controller is just a view, and we have a view model for it. So when the view controller is so complicated, we can divide it into smaller views with their own view models, a table view cell can have its view model if needed, it's similar to your case here.

So we might have a view model like this

```
class CustomControlViewModel: NSObject {
    var data: String!
    var flag: Int!

    init(data: String, flag: Int) {
        self.data = data
        self.flag = flag
    }
}
```

And the data is controlled inside the ViewControllerViewModel

```
func createCustomControlViewModel() -> CustomControlViewModel {
    return CustomControlViewModel(data: "data from view model", flag: 1)
}
```

Hope this answer helps you

Comment: I do have business logic for all the custom controls & hence it makes sense to create view models for each. But  in the main view controllers xib there are no placeholder views for custom controls. I just have a scrollview and depending on the API response I need to invoke an instance of custom control and add it to the scroll view and set constraints. As per your suggestion, I could create customViewControlViewModel but how do I inform the view to invoke an instance of the custom control, add to the scroll view & use the view model created my main view controller view model?

Comment: I think you should have a view to wrap those views, and every time you have to update views from your main view model (after calling the API), you should remove views inside that view and draw them again. Usually the way that we would like to use in this case is using table view, just notify the table to update the cell, it will be recreate based on new data.